# StyleCop settings file could not be saved

Tags: stylecop

I'm having a problem with StyleCop that's driving me nuts. I recently installed it on a new machine and every time I go to edit the master settings file (either via Visual Studio or the StyleCop editor), I'm getting the following error:

> The settings file could not be saved:
>   Access to the path 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft StyleCop
>   4.4.1.1\Settings.StyleCop' is denied.

If I run VS as an administrator I can edit the file but then StyleCop for ReSharper doesn't seem to recognise the rule changes. I've uninstalled and reinstalled various versions with the same end result.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modifying the Settings.StyleCop file in the StyleCop installation directory is possible, but almost always a bad idea.

The best way to go about this kind of thing is to modify the Settings.StyleCop file in the project directory.  I believe one is created when you right-click on a project and open the settings that way.

What often happens though is that you find you need exactly the same settings in ALL your projects, and the settings are wrong until you go through this manual process of configuring the project.  The way around that is this:

Once you have a single project configured the right way, move the Settings.StyleCop file up one directory.  Now you have settings for the *solution* instead of just the *project*.  All projects in the solution will now have the same settings!  This means that now you can create a project-level Settings.StyleCop file for any project that doesn't need the 'typical' settings.  You can even take it a level further and move the Settings.StyleCop file up to the "source control root" (often at least one level higher than the solution level) and now all your solutions will have the same settings.

Comment: My 2 cents: Add the Settings.StyleCop file to your "Solution Items" to ensure it gets checked-in to your source code control - lest if someone checks out your solution that was StyleCop "compliant" he would start receiving warnings that were dealt with all over again

Comment: Oh, absolutely.   Having it as a solution item is the way to go.  I'm actually surprised I didn't mention that myself.

Comment: Here is what I did. From `C:\Program Files (x86)\StyleCop 4.7` **1)** I copied the `Settings.StyleCop` file to my "solution root folder". **2)** In the settings in VS->StyleCop I pointed out this file as "parent directory" seems to save in "program files(x86)" as a global setting. **3)** I opened the `Settings.StyleCop` file through File Explorer as opening it through VS->StyleCop->settings truncated the file. **4)** I can now have the StyleCop editor open and Apply its settings and run StyleCop in VS every second turn until I have the settings I like.

Answer (score 3):

- Right click on project,
- Select StyleCop Settings,
- Navigate to 'Setting Files' tab,
- Select 'Merge with settings file found in parent folders' and click on Edit,
- You will get Warning message.
- On clicking on Yes you are able to edit the StyleCop.settings file.

Note: You are about to edit the default settings which are applied to all code on which this installation of StyleCop is run.

Comment: Note that Settings.StyleCop is now saved in (typically) C:\Program Files (x86)\StyleCop 4.7.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with StyleCop. You are being restricted by Windows security since you're trying to edit something in the Program Files folder. By default StyleCop is set up so that you shouldn't need to edit that file, ever.

Comment: Thanks Jason, so when I go to my StyleCop settings dialogue, choose the "Settings Files" tab then click "Edit" to change the machine definitions, are you saying this shouldn't be done? I assume you're saying the correct practice to only configure settings on a per-project basis?

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers appear to be telling you "don't do this", but if you DO wish this feature to work, as Jason answered, it's a security feature in windows stopping you.

To Fix : Run Visual Studio "as administrator" to make that error go away and allow visual studio to save a file in the program files directory.